# I need to execute a function every x seconds with angular 2 and typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html5-video

this is the function that I want to execute and is in app.component.ts

```
public goLocalization() :void {
    this.localizationService.getLocalizationHttp().then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem("locatios", JSON.stringify(response));
    });
    console.log('goLocalization');
  }
```

from here I'm making the call, but it does not execute and it makes an error

```
<body onLoad="setInterval('goLocalization()',1000);"></body>
```

This is the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: goLocalization is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Why not do that in the app component class's `ngOnInit`?

Comment: You should use (load)='...' for angular context.

Comment: if I could already find a solution using the OnInit interface and using in the function ngOnInit () {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a solution using the OnInit interface and the ngOnInit (){}

in the method I put the following code

```
ngOnInit () {
 setInterval(() => {
      this.goLocalization();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Angular world events are captured using parenthesis. You can capture the load event like you have it but it will require curly braces {{}} to recieve the component context.

The ideal option is to wrap the event name in parenthesis and remove the 'on' text.

```
<body onLoad="{{setInterval('goLocalization()',1000);}}"></body>
```

or

```
<body (load)="setInterval('goLocalization()',1000);"></body>
```

maybe?

```
<body [onLoad]="setInterval('goLocalization()',1000);"></body>
```

Comment: @RicardoValderramaMadrigal that is definitely a better solution for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

body.onLoad will be executed out of angular context, so it can't see goLocalization

What you really should do is

- inject your service in root component
- choose appropriate life cycle stage (on init, on after content init, etc.)
- add it(life cycle interface and method) to your root component (aka AppComponent) and call setInterval with  goLocalization there